# HTTP2 enabled but not supported

Tags: ubuntu, amazon-web-services, virtualhost, http2

I have an AWS Ubuntu 16 Apache Server that is set up to use HTTP2. I have followed every tutorial out there and they all say the same thing:

```
sudo apt-get install software-properties-common
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/apache2
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo a2enmod http2
```

My virtual host file:

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
    Protocols h2 h2c http/1.1
    ServerName clearvision-dev
```

Then sudo service apache2 restart

However when I go to https://tools.keycdn.com/http2-test to test I get the error:

HTTP/2 Test Result www.clearvision-cm.com

Negative! www.clearvision-cm.com does not support HTTP/2.0.
ALPN is not supported.

Please can you help explain what is going wrong?

Comment: You need to make sure you have an OpenSSL version that has ALPN support built-in.

Answer (score 0):

After a ridiculous amount of research and debugging I finally came to the conclusion that http2 is not supported in Ubuntu 16 due to being "experimental". The following is from the relaease notes:

HTTP/2 support in Apache httpd

HTTP/2 support is considered an experimental feature by the Apache httpd upstream project, and so we do not consider it suitable or maintainable for the 5 year supported period of this LTS release. Therefore HTTP/2 support is not available in our builds of Apache httpd.

We expect to issue stable release updates enabling HTTP/2 support after the Apache httpd upstream considers this support to be non-experimental, although this will depend on our assessment of the risk of regression to existing Xenial users at that time.